# regex equivalent to \b that also matches multiple whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

How can I capture the equivalent of `^|\s+|$` within a custom class (or other non-`|`ified means)?

`\b` does not seem to work with `+` (which makes sense).

Is it possible to have the neatness of `\b` for this very similar case? `\b+`, basically.

**Abstract case:**

Subbing out messy text:

```
re.sub(ur'(^|\s+)(someting\simportant)(\s+|$)', lambda x: process_x(x), long_messy_text)
```

where `process_x` has rules about what to do depending on the 'shape' of what it finds (how much padding etc), for docs where it is not desirable to just run through the doc removing *all* extra space etc.

Would be nice to just have one thing, for both sides etc.

**Edit: similar case I just ran into:**

If I have this: `u'T sold a net $746,423 in XCorp'`

And I want this back: `u'$746,423'` and I try to match with this: `\b\$[0-9,]+\b`

But it fails. The dollar amount could also be at the start of the string. And people also do things like `$12mile`.

I am using `(^|\s)`, but a `\b`-like look is what I expect to be able to have.

Comment: What are you trying to match, exactly? What cases is `\b` failing on?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you need this? Or is it just theoretical?

Comment: Edited for actual case.

Comment: I think you mean `^|\s+|$`, don't you?  `\s*` will *always* match, no matter where you apply it.  That makes it useless as a boundary condition.  That's a very common error, even among experienced regex users.  In future remember the rule of thumb, **never use `*` when `+` is what you mean.**

Comment: You're right. I'm trying to think through a larger expression that also includes whole groups of optional stuff (where `\s*` does seem necessary, or at least convenient). Edited with thanks.

Comment: Please provide examples of where you would want this.

Comment: Can you provide a *real example* instead of some abstract possible use case, please?

Comment: What's wrong with the pattern you have there? Applying `$` to the start of a string makes no sense at all, and that should work just fine, no? Regex is meant to be as specific as possible, just like `*` vs `+`. Are you complaining about having to  write something different for the start and end of an expression? You could just make a function to build those regexes for you if you have a lot of them, and just have it pad that with start and end stuff like what you show above, so you don't have to write it every time.

Comment: @poke Sorry, I'm working on someone else's long, multiple option thing. It was using \b, and it was failing, in multiple whitespace cases between groups, to pick up the 'next' optional thing. Then there were other no whitespace cases. That's why I started out talking about `\s*`. People took the time to answer, so once I got some things clarified, I wanted to 'save' the work kindly put in. @melwil I'm not complaining, exactly. This exchange has been great. Thank you; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Anchors like `^` and `$` can't be captured inside anything else, they are not characters. The matched part from these anchors are actually between characters, so `^` matches between nothing and the first character of a string, same for the end of a string with `$`. The moment you put these in a character class they lose their meaning.

Comment: Or change their meaning! `[^inverted-class]`.

Comment: It's not that anchors lose their meaning, by the way, but *operator characters* do. Match question mark or star or parenthesis: `[?*(]`. Anchors are regex operators.

Comment: I never said the anchors lose their meaning. I said that `^$` lose their meaning, as in anchors cannot be inside a character class since they are not characters and match no space. The same goes for all the others you mentioned; `?*(`. I agree that what I said is not completely accurate, and if you feel the need to be more specific, go ahead. Again you are correct, but you are still just digging deeper into what that means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, you can use character class `[\b\s]` in your regex.

Comment: [\b] doesn't work. The [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) lists only `\d` `\D` `\s` `\S` `\w` `\W` as working inside a class.